# Multiple cursors at desired location

Tags: cursor-motions, cursor

I'm using [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) plugin.

I would like to put cursors exactly where I want. For example (`[x]` are the cursor positions):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet[1], consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna[2]
aliqua.
```

In *Sublime Text* I would normally put the first cursor, then go to the next position with the arrows keys and put the second one.

**Is there something similar in VIM?** 
With this plugin or another.

**EDIT**

Following a comment, my interest in doing so appeared when trying to write
`\section[My first section in this book]{My first section in this book}`
in a `.tex` file. My first reaction was to write `\section[]{}` and then put two cursors in order to write the same thing inside the `[]` and `{}`.

Other example would be to add `_someStuff` after several different variables names. For example, turn this:

```
variable1 = 2
my_variable2 = 12
var3 = 14
```

into this:

```
variable1_someStuff = 2
my_variable2_someStuff = 12
var3_someStuff = 14
```

With multiple cursors I can do by selecting a column cursor and then going to the end of the word, then inserting, etc. But I guess I would be easy to choose exactly where I want the cursors to be.

Comment: You could see : https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors/issues/86 and http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4467

Comment: I think that an important question to ask is why do you want to do that? What are you trying to do? Using multiple cursors isn't really "following the Vim way", there is probably a different way to do what you want, at least as efficient, using built-in features.

Comment: @statox. See edit. I gave two examples that came to my mind. The second one I can accomplish with the vim-multiple-cursors plugin, but the first one I can't, at least in an easy manner.

Comment: @Nobe4. Thanks, the second script made it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Using multiple cursor isn't a Vimmer thing**

As I said in the comments using multi cursors (even with a plugin) isn't really "following the Vim way", I totally understand that it is attractive for someone coming from Sublime-Text but you can often find alternatives which are at least as efficient with Vim built-in features.

Of course, finding these alternative solutions isn't always easy and sometimes it takes time but it will get easier with your Vim experience and you'll see that with time multiple cursors will seem totally useless to you.

**That's cool but how can I find an alternative way?**

There is no universal answer since it depends a lot on what you're trying to do, I'll just try to give some hints about the first things to try:

---

**The dot command `.`**

The Dot command is probably one of the most powerful tools in Vim, it simply 
allows us to repeat the last change.  I couldn't explain it better than Drew 
Neil in his [Practical Vim](https://pragprog.com/book/dnvim/practical-vim). I
think that every Vimmer should consider reading this book.

The strength of this command is that the last change can be an action working on
a character, a line or a whole file. For example, a change can be delimited by
the moment you enter insert mode and the moment you go back to normal mode.

With that in mind it is easy to do what you wanted to do with multicursor:

- First let's set up our environment: Let's write as you suggested

  `\section[]{}`
- Then make a **repeatable change**
  The cursor is now on `}`,hit `F[` to go back on the `[` character.
  Then enter insert mode with `i` and type `My first section in this book` and go
  back to normal mode with `ESC`:

  `\section[My first section in this book]{}`
- And here comes the magic part: 
  Let's type `f{` to put the cursor on the `{` character and hit `.` to repeat
  the last change:

  `\section[My first section in this book]{My first section in this book}`

All the challenge of the dot command is to learn how to make repeatable changes:
it will come with grokking Vim but the basic is to understand how to make your
change in a repeatable way.

For example to insert a semi colon at the end of a line you'll prefer using 
`A;` instead of `$a;`. Why?

Because `A;` creates an atomic action so when you'll use `.` on another line, no
matter where you are in the line you'll insert the semi colon at the end.
Whereas when using `$a;` you split your change in two parts `$a` and the
insertion of `;` so if you use `.` it will insert the semi colon on the current
position of the cursor.

**NOTE** The magic formula in Vim is `n.`. A really cool workflow is:

- search for the place you want to make an edit with `/pattern`
- make your repeatable edit
- use `n` to go to the next place to edit
- use `.` to repeat the edit
- repeat the last two steps: You're the king of the world (or at least of
  edits)

---

**macros**

Macros are another extremely important tool in Vim since it allows you to record
a sequence of keystrokes and repeat it as if you typed it again.

I'll use, as an example, your second use case:

```
variable1 = 2
my_variable2 = 12
var3 = 14
```

Once again the important is to learn how to make your macros efficient (I'll
give a counter example just after):

- Put your cursor on the word `variable1` and begin to record your macro with
  `qq`. This means "start recording all my future keystrokes in the register
  named `q`".
- Start making your edit typing:

  - `0` to go at the beginning of the line
  - `e` to go at the end of the first word
  - `a` to append after your cursor
  - `.someStuff` to append the wanted text
  - `<Esc>` to stop the insertion
  - `j` to go on the next line
  - `q` to stop recording the macro
- You'll get:

```
variable1.someStuff = 2
my_variable2 = 12
var3 = 14
```

- Now you can use the macro to repeat your edit. As you are on the right line to
  edit you can simply execute the macro with `@q`. As we want to execute it  twice you can use `2@q` and you'll get the following result:

```
variable1.someStuff = 2
my_variable2.someStuff = 12
var3.someStuff = 14
```

**NOTE 1** As you may have noticed, using `0ea` at the beginning of the macro
was really important. Indeed, if you had put your cursor at the end of the first
word before recording the macro and executing it again your result would have
been:

```
variable1.someStuff = 2
my_variable2 = 12.someStuff
var3 = 14.someStuff
```

As your cursor the text would have been inserted at the position of the cursor
after changing of line (i.e. the end of the line in this case)

**NOTE 2** Macros are extremely powerful and you can even create recursive
macros when you are comfortable with them. Here your macro could have been:

```
`0ea.someStuff<Esc>j@q`
```

The final `@q` would have called the macro by itself instead of using `2@q`; you'd
just have used `@q` and all the work would have been done.

---

**visual block**

Here comes another trick that doesn't directly apply to your use case but can
be really useful to edit a large number of line at the same time. Let's get this
extract of CSS code:

```
li.one   a{ background-image: url('/images/sprite.png'); }
li.two   a{ background-image: url('/images/sprite.png'); }
li.three a{ background-image: url('/images/sprite.png'); }
```

What if you moved the sprites from `images` to `components`?

Well you can put your cursor on the `i` of `images` and press `<C-v>`. This will
start the visual block mode which allows to select blocks. Now you can type `t/`
to select the word you want to change and `2j` to select all the occurrences of the
word.

After that you simply have to type `c` to change the word and then `components`.
When you'll go out of insert mode you'll see:

```
li.one   a{ background-image: url('/components/sprite.png'); }
li.two   a{ background-image: url('/components/sprite.png'); }
li.three a{ background-image: url('/components/sprite.png'); }
```

---

**The global command**

The global command is a tool which allows to apply an ex mode command on lines
matching a pattern, once again that's a good way to apply the same change on
different place without needing multiple cursors.

The syntax is the following:

```
:[range] g / pattern / command
```

For more details on the `[range]` parameter please see `:h :range`. I won't detail
it here, I'll simply remind that `%` represents the whole file, `'<,'>`
represents the last selection, and `1,5` represents the lines 1 to 5 of the
file.

This parameter defines the lines which will be treated by the global command. If
no range is specified, then the global command will use `%` by default.

The [pattern] argument is a search pattern as you are used to use with the search
engine. As it integrates the search history you can leave this field blank and
the global command will then use the last search pattern in the search history.

Finally the [command] parameter is an ex command as you are probably used to.

Now the behavior of the global command is pretty simple:

- Iterate through all the lines defined in the [range] parameter
- If the current line matches the defined pattern, apply the command

As the [command] parameter is an ex command, you can do a lot of things. Let's
take the following pseudo code which isn't pretty interesting and have a lot of
debugging messages:

```
var myList  = null
var i       = 0

myList = new List()
echo "List instantiated"

for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    myList.Add(i)
    echo i . " added to the list"

echo "end of for loop"
```

Now let's say that you're sure this code works and you want to delete these
useless `echo` statements:

- You can apply your global command on the whole file so you'll have to prepend
  the command with `%` (or with nothing since `%` is the default range).
- You know that the lines you want delete all matches the pattern `echo`
- You want to delete these lines so you'll have to use the command `:delete`
  which can also be abbreviated as `d`

So you'll simply have to use the following function:

```
:%global/echo/delete
```

Which can also be abbreviated as

```
:g/echo/d
```

Note that `%` disappeared, `global` is abbreviated as `g` and `delete` as `d`.
As you might imagine the result is:

```
var myList  = null
var i       = 0

myList = new List()

for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    myList.Add(i)
```

**NOTE 1** An important point that took me some time to realize is that the
`normal` command is an ex command which means that you can use it with the
global command. That can be really powerful: let's say that I want to duplicate
all the lines which contains echo, I don't need a macro or even the magic
formula `n.`. I can simply use

```
:g/echo/normal YP
```

And voila:

```
var myList  = null
var i       = 0

myList = new List()
echo "List instantiated"
echo "List instantiated"

for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    myList.Add(i)
    echo i . " added to the list"
    echo i . " added to the list"

echo "end of for loop"
echo "end of for loop"
```

**NOTE 2** "Hey what if I want to use my command on lines which doesn't match a
specific pattern?"

`global` has an opposite command `vglobal` abbreviated `v` which works exactly
like `global` except that the command will be applied on lines which don't
match the [pattern] parameter. This way if we apply

```
:v/echo/d
```

On our previous example we get:

```
echo "List instantiated"
    echo i . " added to the list"
echo "end of for loop"
```

The `delete` command has been applied on lines which didn't contained `echo`.

---

Here I hope that those few hints will give you ideas on how to get rid of your
multi cursor plugin and use Vim in the Vim way ;-)

As you can imagine these examples are pretty simple and are just made to
demonstrate that when you follow the Vim way you really rarely need several
cursors. My advice would be when you encounter a situation where you think it
would be useful, write it down and take some time later to find a better
solution. 99% of the time you'll eventually find a faster/more efficient way to
do it.

Also I will repeat myself one more time but I really encourage you to read
[Practical Vim](https://pragprog.com/book/dnvim/practical-vim) by Drew Neil
because this book is not about "How to do that or this in Vim" it is about "How
to learn to think in the Vim way" which will allow you to built your own
solution to your future problems in a good way.

---

**PS** Special thanks to @Alex Stragies for his editing work and the corrections
he made to this long post.

Comment: Very complete answer. I actually did know all those commands, but never thought of using them like that... I guess I need more practice. However, I must say that sometimes the 'vim-way' takes longer than just using some plugin (for example, your CSS example can be done much quicker with the plugin I mentioned), and sometimes it takes much shorter (actually, the vast majority of times vim is faster than any text editor, if used properly).

Comment: Btw, I think your answer is already pretty complete. I will accept it, but if you want to add more details, please do and I'll be glad to read them.

Comment: @tomasyany: Indeed sometimes using the "vim way" might seem longer (I can't count how many times I spend more time on creating a working macro than if I had done the changes manually) but with the practice it eventually get faster. I've been using Vim for only one year and I'm (very) far from being an expert but I can feel that my editing continuously improves as I practice.

Comment: Should probably mention the `gn` text object as well. It addresses some use cases of multiple cursors. Search with `/`, then `dgn` or `cgn`, then repeat with `.`.

Comment: @Justin I'm not really familiar with `gn` I'll give it a try and add it after. Thanks for the head up!

Comment: it's jolly nice, congrats. But then why is a Visual Block where you select n lines aligned together in a visual way "the vim way", but something more way logical like "select every second word of n lines" NOT the vim way? For me, all those solutions don't come even close to the desired result.

Comment: @Salomanuel I'm not sure what exactly you are talking about with you example. But I think what's important to take from this answer is that you can't really have a multi-cursor in Vim but there are alternative. Now about following the Vim way I think one should not take that too seriously: As long as you are efficient with your editor it's all that matters. "Following the vim way" is just a way to say that some things can't be done efficiently in a certain way with Vim and so it's better not to fight against that but instead using the tools available.

Comment: actually the below answer `3:norm ea_somestuff` really hits the mark. That really feels vim-like instead of "monkey-patchy"

Comment: I don't see how any of what's in this answer is monkey patching since it is exclusively built-in features and at no point I invite the reader to add custom code. But of course the `normal` command associated with ranges is super powerful and can be used in a lot of situation.

Answer (score 9):

More Vim ways.

**First task:**

```
\section[foobar baz]{foobar baz}
```

Workflow:

```
\section[]{}
hh
ifoobar baz<Esc>
$.
```

**Second task:**

```
variable1 = 2
my_variable2 = 12
var3 = 14
```

Command:

```
3:norm ea_somestuff
```

Result:

```
variable1_somestuff = 2
my_variable2_somestuff = 12
var3_somestuff = 14
```

Answer (score 6):

Your given use-cases to me sound like to want to know the `.` key command (repeat last Editing command)

- Go to first place, press `i`, insert your text, `<ESC>`
- move to location 2, press `.` (Dot) ==> Identical Text is inserted
- To move down one line here and insert again (when inserting into consecutive lines), press `<ALT>-j.`

Your tex example for me is solved by:

`I\section[]{}<ESC>hhiMy first Sec...<ESC>lll.`

Comment: It's a pretty nice solution. I knew perfectly the `.` key command, but never thought of using it that way. I agree it is a nice way. But your answer doesn't actually refer to the real question, so it wouldn't be appropriate to accept it I guess.

Comment: Well, your question (after you added the desired use-cases) reminded me of "I really like my scissors, and want to tighten a screw with them. Tell me how". And me pointing you to a nifty use for a screwdriver ;)  (I added as an answer, because i don't know, how to do formatting in comments)

Comment: This feels slower than using a mouse in vscode or something and placing cursors at desired location and typing.

Comment: @AlexStragies to me it sounds like "I always cut fabric with normal scissors, can I do it in Vim?" "no you cannot, you have to buy specialised fabric scissors, but they work differently and only cut one piece of fabric a the time. Else you can use industrial laser cutters than take half a day to configure before cutting."
(and I've been using and loving vim for years)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but there is one other command I use a lot in Vi for these sorts of things and I didn't see it mentioned.
That is the `:map` command, which is much like the macro `q` but uses ex commands and is tied to a single keystroke. After all, Vi is all about single key commands!

Where it really shines is where there is a ton of repetitive editing keystrokes required and your brain/fingers can't keep the sequence in order—especially at speed!
*Note: I like using the back-tick `` ` `` key as it's only used for jumping to marks as a Vi command.*

So for the first request you could do:

```
:map ` %iMy first section in this book[Ctrl]+[v][Esc]3l.
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> will be replaced with `^[` (Esc char representation) and will display as:

```
:map ` %iMy first section in this book^[3l.
```

Now if your cursor is on that line and you press the `` ` `` key (in normal mode) you will insert the text between two following pairs of brackets/braces next to each other.  Here's the breakdown:

- `:map`  starts the ex mapping of the next key given
- `` ` ``  (back-tick) key to map; others can be used but may be Vi command keys
- `%` puts the cursor on the first matching bracket/brace of the cursor line
- `i` set insert mode
- `…` text to insert is typed
- `^[`  represents an Esc char (Ctrl+v,Esc) and quits insert mode
- `3l`  moves cursor to the next matching brace
- `.`  repeats the last insert command

Ok, so not terribly elegant for the first case maybe, but for the next case, given

```
variable1 = 2
my_variable2 = 12
var3 = 14
```

You could do the following:

```
:map ` 0ei_somestuff[Ctrl]+[v][Esc]j
```

With the cursor on the first line, pressing `` ` `` three times would give the desired results.  The ex commands can be understood by reading some of the above methods.

---

#### More Notes

1. If you don't get the ex commands right the first time, type `:` and use <kbd>Up</kbd> to re-call and edit your map command.
2. If you happen to over-write a Vi command key, say `a`, to get it back, just use `:unmap a` to reset it.
3. List of all defined mappings by using `:map` by itself.

Comment: These days with Vim, I would prefer `:noremap` and a mode-specific variant if possible (`:nnoremap` for normal mode); you can map more than one keystroke; backtick is used to jump to marks; you can use key notation in mappings (`<esc>`); etc.

Comment: Thanks for the clean up of formatting @D.BenKnoble and key notation hint.  I didn't know that one. I'll check out `:noremap` as well.  Not something I've used either! :v)