# How to add space on multiple lines when pressing spacebar (without extra configuration)?

Tags: insert-mode, visual-mode, replace

I tried visual block, but visual block only allow to highlight or delete characters on multiple lines.

Is there any function that allows to add space before the first character of multiple lines when I press spacebar?

Comment: Very similar question with a useful answer: [Multiple cursors at desired location](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4307/51)

Answer (score 32):

You were right about visual mode, but you should have tried *blockwise visual mode* by pressing `<C-V>`.

In blockwise visual mode you can select the lines and columns of your selection. When you selected the desired lines of the block you want, you can press `I` (that is `Shift + i`), you are now on insert mode, where you can add space in front of your line.

When you press `<ESC>` the new spaces will be added to all lines of your selection.

Comment: Related q: find and replace in multiple rows at the same time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552346/how-can-i-select-multiple-lines-in-visual-mode-in-vim

Answer (score 8):

To add a space at the beginning of mutliple lines you also can use the `normal` command. Let's say you have the following file:

```
" foo
" bar
buzz
fizz
```

You can select the lines you want to add a space on and use the command

```
:'<,'> norm I
```

***Note the space character after the `I`***. The command means:

```
:'<,'>      For the line I selected
norm        Execute the following sequence of keystrokes as if I was in normal mode
I           Insert at the beginning of the line the following characters
[space]     A space
```

I you select the 3 first lines you'll get:

```
 " foo
 " bar
 buzz
fizz
```

---

For even more power you can combine the `normal` command with the `global` command to apply the transformation only on lines matching a pattern. If you want to add a space in front of the commented lines in our previous example you can use:

```
:g/"/norm I
```

to apply `norm I` on lines containing `"`. ***Note the space character after the `I`***

Which will give you:

```
 " foo
 " bar
buzz
fizz
```

Answer (score 4):

Lets say you want to prepend 2 spaces to beginning of the line for 7 lines.

Approach 1:
`:set number` and then we can add spaces to the beginning of the lines we want. Like for example `:22,29s/^/  /`

so here the `22,29` is the line range and `:s` is short for `:substitute` and `/^` is to search at beginning of the lines and the 2 spaces are to replace the beginning of line in the given range with 2 spaces

Approach 2:
`:set shiftwidth=2` and `:set number` and `:22,29>` where > is for adding the width which is 2 spaces in this case

Comment: Note that `set number` is useful to know what is the number of your lines but it has no effects on the commands you mention. You could have `set nonumber` or `set relativenumber` and that would work the same.