# Writing text to multiple lines in different locations of the text file

Tags: visual-mode

One feature useful to me is Ctr-V column visual mode. This way I can avoid typing lines nearly the same multiple times. Is there a way in vim I can do this over a range like 5,14,22,.. so that the change is applied to those lines as well?

Comment: You could use a macro, or the :t Ex-command, or C-x C-l line completion. But i dont think you can get split multiple cursors. A :g command might do it if the insert region is delimited by a pattern.

Comment: Your question makes me me think of [Multiple cursors at desired location](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4307/1841) where I wrote an answer which could interest you.

Answer (score 1):

Not without a plugin.

There are a handful of plugins with "multi-cursor", "multi-line" and/or "multi-edit" functionality.

At least one emulates the multi-cursor behavior found in the Sublime editor: https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors. The basic functionality is to place cursors wherever you like by clicking and then start typing. The text will appear simultaneously at every location with a cursor. You can also place the cursors based on a regex rather than where you click your mouse. I've installed this one and it works pretty well but I don't use it all that much since it's not a way of working that I find myself unable to replicate or approximate by other means.

Another operates a lot like Visual mode except you can select non-contiguous sections of text: https://github.com/alfredodeza/plexer.vim . I haven't tried this one.

I'm sure there are others.