# How to write on multiple places at once

Tags: visual-mode, visual-block

I'm familiar with vertical blocks, and I often `ctrl+v` `down` `down` `down` `shift+I` `foobar` `esc` to write foobar in various locations at once. 
This is useful if I want to replace `<td>` to `<th>` in a chain, for instance.

Since not all the text blocks are of equal size, I don't know how to do the same for `</td>` to `</th>`. I can think of selecting multiple lines as I did earlier, move to the end of the line with `shift+a`, maybe, move one to the left, delete a character with `x`, and type my `h`, but I don't know how to move my position(s) when I am in visual block mode.

Is there a way to select a position as active, and move as I usually would with my marker, choosing where to write?

In SublimeText3 I would do something like `ctrl+d` to select the cases I'm looking for (skipping with `ctrl+k+d` if necessary), moving to the end-of-line with `end` (`home` for the beginning of the line), and then moving with the arrow keys (alternatively with `ctrl`+arrow keys).

An example scenario:

```html
<tr>
    <th>Language</th>
    <th>Oral</th>
    <th>Written</th>
    <th>Diplomas</th>
    <th>Notes</th>
</tr>
```

which I want to be

```html
<tr>
    <td>Language</td>
    <td>Oral</td>
    <td>Written</td>
    <td>Diplomas</td>
    <td>Notes</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I gues you want https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors

Comment: Interesting plugin. I might take a look at it on my home machine. Is there a native way to do the same, or similar?

Comment: There is. But you need to provide a text sample. It's hard to understand what you really want.

Comment: I've added my scenario.

Comment: A few years ago we had a question about [multiple cursors](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4307/1841) and I think it is pretty related to this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the suggested plugin `vim-multiple-cursors`, you have different options:

For example you can go on the parent tag (`tr` I guess?) and visual select in the tag:

```
vit
```

Then do a substitution in the `tr` tag only:

```
:'<,'>s/td/th/g
```

If you want to do a more complex change than a substitution, you can search for a pattern matching all the places you want to apply a change, go to the first one, do your change, and for all the other, if the change is atomic, use `.` to repeat it:

```
/td>
ceth<esc>
n.n.n.
```

The first command searches for a `td>` tag, the second cut until the end (`ce`) and types `th`, then leaves the insert mode. The third line goes to the next `td` (`n`), execute the second command (`.`) and this 3 times (do it as many times as you need of course, it is just an example).

If the change is more complex, you can also create a macro.

There is an interesting article about multiple cursor (or rather lack of) in Vim: https://medium.com/@schtoeffel/you-don-t-need-more-than-one-cursor-in-vim-2c44117d51db

Comment: I neither know how to do a substitution in a selected mode (`vit` is great to select my tags to apply it too, though!), nor how to use move my cursor after having found my matches with `n` Can you explain this?

Comment: For the first one, do a visual selection, then press `:` to enter in command mode, it will show: `:\<,\>` which means "type a command that I will run in a range (`\<` being the beginning of the selection and `\>` being the end. Your command would look like: `:\<,\>s/td/th/g`.

Comment: When you do a search in Vim, you can then go from result to result of your search with the `n` key. I am updating my answer with an example.

Comment: Interesting. Knowing RegEx, I find the substitution method really nice. What effect does the last /g mean? I assume global.

Comment: yes, global, especially in his case where he wants to replace both start and end `td` tags of the lines

Comment: @padawin thanks for the link, never know cgn

Comment: Actually, the range is `'<,'>`

Answer (score 2):

I know there has already answers. But i couldn't help to try something i just learned from @padawin's link.

1. `/th>` search th>
2. `cgntd>` change `th>` to `td>`
3. `.........` repeat 9 times with 9 dots. You can just press the button, don't lift it.

check :h gn

**update**

If your text doesn't contain `th`, place your cursor under `th`, you can replace word under cursor like this:

1. `*#cgntd`

   - `*`  set @/ to `\v<th>`, search forward
   - `#`  search backward, restore cursor, you can also use `N` if you want.
   - `cgntd` replace next match (or the one under cursor) to `td`
2. `.........`

   - repeat, You can hold `.` , don't release

Comment: Indeed, I just played a bit with it too, it is definitely promising! I'll try to keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Building on padawin’s answer, I would go to the `<tr>` tag, `vit`, and then

```
:s-<\(/\)?th>-<\1td>-g
```

To do the replacement. If your text doesn’t contain `th`, then `:s/th/td/g` is simpler.

Alternately, with tpope’s [surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin, on each `th`, do `cst<td>`.  Combined with tpope’s [repeat](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat), you can do this for one line and repeat on each with the `.` command, or even `:g/<th>/normal f>lcst<td>`

Answer (score 1):

I use [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) which makes changing tags easier, e.g. `cst<td>`. Combine this with `:normal` and a visual mode makes this pretty easy. Just visually select the lines with `V` then run:

```
:norm cst<td>
```

For more help see:

```
:h :range
:h :norm
:h V
```

Comment: Nice to see a similar idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

Note: Not an answer anymore after your last update to the question, but perhaps still useful to know.

---

Try it like this:

1. Goto end of first line.
2. Hit `<Ctrl-V>$`
3. Move down
4. Hit `Afoobar<esc>`

With the `$` you hit in step 2, the visual block selection is always till end-of-line. Even if one of the following lines is shorter.

Comment: This works if I delete all the end-of-line > tags in the html, and add them in the foobar. I tried tricking it with I, but that worked out wrong. Can I somehow tell it to move one position to the left?

Comment: @mazunki I don't think this is possible. I would do it with search/replace. See the answer from D. Ben Knoble.