# How to vertically-block-select words of different length?

Tags: selection

With other editors we can select vertical-blocks where each line has the same start column but not the same end-column.

For example:

```
print("", s.field1);
print("", s.field_long);
print("", s.f);
```

Is there a way in Vim (with a plugin or not) to select the block from the snippet above:

```
field1
field_long
f
```

Can we tell vim to select everything up to a certain character?

A more powerful variant could be to tell Vim select everything between two characters going left and right from the currently selected column.

*EDIT*:
Doing tricks with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> does not work as it always selected a rectangle. Here I vertically selected the `f`s and then did <kbd>w</kbd> for word-skip.

[image]

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, but you might be interested by my answer to [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4307/1841): There are plugins which allows you to do what you want and there is probably a built-in feature which will allow you to do what you want but we would need more details on your final goal to help you efficiently. There is also `<C-v>$y` that you could use to yank the text you want to use followed by `s:/);//` to remove the unwanted characters.

Comment: I use VSCode, and in insert mode I can do `ctrl+shift+down` `ctrl+right arrow` to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the first letter of the word, and press

```
<C-v>w
```

that selects the word. You may use

```
<C-v>5w
```

to select e.g. 5 words. Then you do whatever you want, e.g. to copy to clipboard you do

```
" * y
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. C-v is selecting a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves:

```
/field1<CR><C-v>2jf)
```