# Operator Modifier

Tags: normal-mode, operator

I have been using vim mode for atom for quite a while,
recently I've been trying to switch to nvim, but I can't seem to find a way to replicate the [operator modifiers](https://github.com/t9md/atom-vim-mode-plus/wiki/OccurrenceModifier) behaviour, which I've come to rely on quite frequently.

So for example, in the following paragraph:

```
hello this is me
writing to say hello
to everyone, so hello
```

Let's say that I wanted to change every occurrence of the word **hello** to the word **hi**, I could do that by navigating my cursor over any of the occurrences of **hello** and typing:

> coip

I can't seem to find a convenient way to replace this behaviour, I'm open to any plugin suggestions as well, but a modifier like "o" seems pretty useful (or perhaps I'm missing a better way to do things).

Comment: I'm not sure the question is an exact duplicate but I think the answer I wrote [there](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4307/1841) might answer your question. Here I would simply use `:%s/hello/hi/g` or a `:%s/hello/hi/gc` if you need to select which occurrences you want to change, but the closest of what you want is to use the dot command (explained in my other answer)

Comment: I'm interested. What's the behavior when current character is not a `word character`? e.g. cursor on `;` of `void foo();`.

Comment: it finds every occurrence of ; and changes it as well from what I can see

Answer (score 3):

That is indeed a novel and potentially time-saving feature!

The way to do this in plain Vim would be using `:substitute` for a range; the pattern can be easily set via `*` when the cursor is on top of it:

```
*vip:s//hi/g<CR>
```

A mapping for the `:s///g` part that puts the cursor right into the replacement part can save many keystrokes here.

In order to support arbitrary text objects (`ip` covers entire lines, which plays well with the `:{range}`, but objects like `is` don't), the [vis.vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1195) plugin can help.

#### Plugin alternatives

I'm not aware of any plugin that implements this for Vim; however, my [ChangeGlobally plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4321) offers something similar: Instead of having a fixed text (the *cword* with the operator modifier) applied over the specified `{motion}`, it applies the change or delete of a specified `{motion}` over a fixed range. I think the implementation could also support the other use case; I might add that to it ...

**Update**: I've added similar mappings to my plugin. Instead of the `o` operator modifier, I went with the plugin's existing mapping scheme. (Also, the plugin only handles changes and deletions, and cannot be applied to other actions like `gU`.)

These are the new mappings:

```
[N]["x]gc*{motion}      Delete the current whole \<word\> [into register x]
                        and start inserting. After exiting insert mode, that
                        text substitution is applied to all / the first [N]
                        occurrences inside {motion} text.

[N]["x]gx*{motion}      Delete the current whole \<word\> [into register x]
                        and apply the deletion to all / the first [N]
                        occurrences inside {motion} text.

[N]["x]gcg*{motion}     Delete the current word [into register x] and
                        start inserting. After exiting insert mode, that text
                        substitution is applied to all / the first [N]
                        occurrences inside {motion} text.

[N]["x]gxg*{motion}     Delete the current word [into register x] and
                        apply the deletion to all / the first [N] occurrences
                        inside {motion} text.

[N]["x]gc_ALT-8{motion} Delete the current whole \_sWORD\_s [into register x]
                        and ALT-8t inserting. After exiting insert mode, that
                        text substitution is applied to all / the first [N]
                        occurrences inside {motion} text.

[N]["x]gx_ALT-8{motion} Delete the current whole \_sWORD\_s [into register x]
                        and apply the deletion to all / the first [N]
                        occurrences inside {motion} text.

[N]["x]gcg_ALT-8{motion}Delete the current WORD [into register x] and
                        ALT-8t inserting. After exiting insert mode, that text
                        substitution is applied to all / the first [N]
                        occurrences inside {motion} text.

[N]["x]gxg_ALT-8{motion}Delete the current WORD [into register x] and
                        apply the deletion to all / the first [N] occurrences
                        inside {motion} text.

[N]["x]<Leader>gc{source-motion}{target-motion}
                        Delete {source-motion} text [into register x] and
                        start inserting. After exiting insert mode, that text
                        substitution is applied to all / the first [N]
                        occurrences inside {target-motion} text.
{Visual}[N]["x]<Leader>gc{motion}
                        Delete the selected text [into register x] and start
                        inserting. After exiting insert mode, that text
                        substitution is applied to all / the first [N]
                        occurrences inside {motion} text.

[N]["x]<Leader>gx{source-motion}{target-motion}
                        Delete the {source-motion} text [into register x] and
                        apply the deletion to all / the first [N] occurrences
                        inside {target-motion} text.
{Visual}[N]["x]<Leader>gx{motion}
                        Delete the selected text [into register x] and apply
                        the deletion to all / the first [N] occurrences inside
                        {motion} text.
```

Comment: Yes, I was already aware of substitutions, but I am really not a fan of them, they take way too many keystrokes :P but your change globally plugin looks pretty cool, I might try it out. Thanks for putting time into that, if you could support the "o" modifier as well, that would be awesome!

Comment: Okay, I just tried it, just to document this. To achieve the same thing I can go `viwgc` but it does delete one character too far to the left (I might be doing it wrong). I can't figure out how to apply it to a paragraph either.

Comment: That one-off might be a discrepancy of Neovim; it should work (with any value of `'selection'`) in Vim. Yes, it currently auto-applies the changes to the current line / whole buffer / `[N]` times. To support passed text objects as the scope of application, a different mapping needs to be implemented.

Comment: So, I just updated your plugin and tried `gc*` over a word, and I got an error `E119: Not enough arguments for function: ChangeGlobally#OperatorExpression`. Is that an invalid usage? The error occurred before I could specify a motion

Comment: That should not happen. Do you use that in NeoVim or Vim?

Comment: It is in neovim.

Comment: Do you aim to support neovim as well. I was under the impression that neovim and vim have the same plugin architecture (but I've never written a plugin), a plugin like this is a really good reason to stick to vim.

Comment: Yes, that's also my understanding, that they are mostly compatible. I don't test my plugins with Neovim, but if someone sends a reasonable patch to fix a compatibility problem, I'd certainly accept it.