# How to multicut, edit and paste word after a word

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Want to find a way to do in vim what I usually do in other text editors. It's really hard to describe the problem, so I've created a gif and attached it to this question.

Initial document state:

```
inv/stage  
inv/production  
inv/test  
inv/robot
```

I want to cut all `inv`s, remove `/` before the word, add `.` after the word, and paste what had been cut. So in the end, the state of the document is:

```
stage.inv  
production.inv  
test.inv  
robot.inv
```

[image]

Comment: Multiple cursors is one of the more frequently asked about topics here. This question might not be the closest match to yours, but it has a fairly thorough selection of answers: [Multiple cursors at desired location](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4307/multiple-cursors-at-desired-location)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are several options:

- A single substitute command. `:[range]substitute,inv/\(\w\+\),\1.inv,` (note the use of `,` as separator to avoid escaping the slash in `inv/`). If the `inv` was variable, use `:s,\(\w\+\)/\(\w\+\),\2.\1,` (and `\v` very magic mode makes some of those backslashes unnecessary).
- A macro. Record `qq0df/A.<esc>px` and replay using any of `@q`+`j@@` or `:[range]normal! @q` (where `[range]` selects your content; easiest in this case is `vip:`).
- A *recursive* macro. Clear the register `qqq` and then record `qq0df/A.<esc>pxj@q`. Now replay once `@q`. Will stop at the end of the buffer or on a line not containing `/`, whichever comes first.
- A single normal command. Similar to the macro, especially the `:[range]normal! @q` version. Just use `:[range]normal! 0df/A.<esc>px`, only this time you need to type the escape literally (using `<C-v><esc>`). Again, in this case, `vip:` gets you started with the `:[range]`.
- A global command. Avoid the range with `:global,inv/,` and either `normal!` or `substitute` afterwards.

---

You can *cut* the first bit with visual block mode, since it's so regular: `<C-v>f/4jd`. But pasting it won't work like you think, so then you're left with `A.inv<esc>` followed by repeating `j.` on each line. That's a bit slow to me: it took me longer to come up with than any of the 4 options above, and is slower to actually perform on anything more than one or two lines.