# How to append to the end of word with one key stroke?

Tags: cursor-motions

Is it possible to start insertion in the end of word with a single keystroke? Currently I am using `ea`, but it does not allow me to use `.` to repeat the same action.

I really love `A` and `I` which operate with a line. Is there the same alternative, which operates with a word either `w` or `W`?

Let's say I have these lines:

```
object_name = "foo"
another_long_object_name = "bar"
again_different_length_word_which_needs_same_modification = "spam"
```

I would like to press a keystroke when standing in the middle of `object_name` and add a suffix `_id` then repeat the `j.` command two times to get this result:

```
object_name_id = "foo"
another_long_object_name_id = "bar"
again_different_length_word_which_needs_same_modification_id = "spam"
```

Comment: You could try to create a mapping but the repeatable part might be tricky. So what about using a macro? First `qq` to start recording in the `q` buffer, then `ea_id` to add `_id` at the end of the word, then optionally `j0` to go at the beginning of the next line and finally `q` again to stop recording. You can then use `@q` to execute the macro once or `5@q` to run it 5 times (that's when the `j0` becomes useful). Or if the situation allows it (like in your example) a simple substitution command `:%s/\w\+/&_id`

Comment: @statox sounds like an answer!

Comment: Ooh. If only you were dealing with _words_ rather than _WORDS_ because this would do, I think: `nnoremap <leader>X a<c-g>U<c-right><c-g>U<left>`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Since you already posted an answer feel free to add the macro and substitution solutions in it I'm completely fine with that :)

Comment: @niekas I just remember about a pretty complete answer I wrote a while back on the question "[Multiple cursors at desired location](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4312/1841)". I think you'll probably want to read it because that might give you a few ideas.

Comment: @statox CW'd it; felt like it stood separately enough that it should be voted on its own.

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble that's great moderator work right here ;)

Comment: @statox need a “heart” instead of an upvote :) no need to bump that comment up with an upvote, but I want to say “thanks”!

Comment: Are you Asking "end or word" or "the end of words" or are you saying that doesn't matter?

You might map anything onto a single keystroke but where would that actually get you?

For a trite example, how would you distinguish among "This is simple…" or "These are simplistic…"?

Comment: I've rolled back the latest edit. Solutions do not belong in Question bodies. They can be posted as (self) Answers, and voted or accepted as warranted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> object_name = "foo"
> another_long_object_name = "bar"
> again_different_length_word_which_needs_same_modification = "spam"
> ```
>
> I would like to press a keystroke when standing in the middle of object_name and add a suffix _id then repeat the j. command two times to get this result:

The way I do that is `ce<Ctrl-r>-_id`. You can repeat that with `.` since it's a single normal mode operation. The steps are:

1. `ce` change to end of word, stay in insert mode
2. `<Ctrl-r>-` insert what you just deleted with `ce` (the contents of the `-` register)
3. continue inserting `_id`

Here's what `ce<Ctrl-R>-_id<Esc>j.j.` gets you:

```
object_name_id = "foo"
another_long_object_name_id = "bar"
again_different_length_word_which_needs_same_modification_id = "spam"
```

> I really love A and I which operate with a line. Is there the same alternative, which operates with a word either w or W?

Unfortunately, all keys have other uses. You could `:nmap` operations like `ea`, `bi`, etc. to a new key sequence, or overwrite a single key's previous use. However, `.` would only repeat the last *native* normal-mode operation, rather than the whole mapping. There seems to be a [repeat.vim](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/creating-repeatable-mappings-with-repeat-vim/) plugin that allows repeating whole mappings with `.`, though. EDIT: This plugin won't work for this use-case though, because it requires appending a function call to the mapping and we can't do that because we want it to leave us in insert mode.

`I` and `A` are only shortcuts of `^i` and `$a` because those movement and operation combinations are so common. I don't think `ea`, `bi`, `Ea`, and `Bi` are equally as common to justify getting a separate single-keystroke equivalent each when vim is already lacking keys. The only real benefit I think would be simpler repeatability, but that can be worked around like I described above with `ce` for `ea` and `cE` for `Ea`. For `bi` and `Bi`, you can typically do `<Ctrl-v><vertical-movements>I`, though you could also do `cbfoo_<Ctrl-r>-<Esc>j.j.` for `bi` and with `cB` for `Bi` if that's somehow better:

```
foo_object_name = "foo"
foo_another_long_object_name = "bar"
foo_again_different_length_word_which_needs_same_modification = "spam"
```

Comment: I was able to achieve `A` alternative for `w` and `W` with mappings `map <a-a> ce<c-r>-` and `map <a-A> cE<c-r>-`. Now I can press `Alt+a` to append to word. However, I would like to have the same shortcuts for `I`, but `cb<c-r>-` and `cB<c-r>-` does not work, because `<c-r>` moves the cursor after the pasted content. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: @niekas No. You'd just have to type out `cb<your-prefix><c-r>-` when you want this. Even the repeat.vim plugin I mentioned won't let you create a repeatable mapping for `bi` because it requires appending a function call to end of the mapping, and you can't do that because you want it to leave you in insert mode. If you really, really want this mapping, I would suggest looking into modifying repeat.vim to see if it's possible to work around that requirement to let you prepend the function call instead, or by this point it may be simpler to modify the vim source code to add the commands.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative: use a search motion for “move and repeat” (`n.`):

```
/^\w\+\>/e<cr>a_id<esc>n.n.
```

A simpler search pattern in this case might be `/ =`.

Answer (score 6):

From [@statox](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1841/statox) in the [comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/36462/how-to-append-to-the-end-of-word-with-one-key-stroke/36463#comment65404_36462):

> You could try to create a mapping but the repeatable part might be tricky. So what about using a macro? First `qq` to start recording in the `q` buffer, then `ea_id` to add `_id` at the end of the word, then optionally `j0` to go at the beginning of the next line and finally `q` again to stop recording. You can then use `@q` to execute the macro once or `5@q` to run it 5 times (that's when the `j0` becomes useful). Or if the situation allows it (like in your example) a simple substitution command `:%s/\w\+/&_id`

Answer (score 4):

For things like this I often reach for `:normal`. I imagine a `q` & `@` would also work here:

```
:%norm ea_id
```

The idea is to run a set of normal command on a given range (whole buffer, `%`, in the above example). So go to the end of the first word, `e`, and append `_id` via `a_id`

You can use visual mode if you want with `:normal` to supply a range

For more help see:

```
:h :normal
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to suffix multiple occurrences of a word searched with `/`, you could **suffix your search with `/e` [[example](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Searching#:%7E:text=while%20/green/e%20positions%20the%20cursor%20at%20the%20end%20of%20the%20next%20%22green%22.)] to position the cursor at the end of your search match**, then you just press `a` to insert suffix, which is repeatable with `.`. E.g:

- `/object_name/e`
- then `a` `_id`
- then repeat `n.` to suffix the next `object_name` into `object_name_id`

It's not exactly what you're after and won't work with your last example, but it will for the first two and may be good enough in most cases.

Also if you don't want to retype the whole word to search for it with the `/e` suffix, you could use `*` then `/<ctrl+p>/e`.

Comment: In fact, `*//e` will work (no C-p needed)