# How to insert to the beginning of a word with one key stroke?

Tags: cursor-motions

Is it possible to start insertion in the beginning of a word when standing in the middle of it with a single keystroke? Currently I am using `bi` or `Bi`, but it does not allow me to use `.` to repeat the same action.

I really love `A` and `I` which operate with a line. I am looking for alternative commands which operate with `w` and `W`. I was able to find a replacement for `ea` and `Ea`, see
[How to append to the end of word with one key stroke?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/36462/147) However, its not so easy for `bi` and `Bi`.

Let's say we have these lines:

```
random_name: SomeKindOfType = "foo"
long_name: AnotherType = "bar"
short_name: ThirdType = "spam"
```

And I want to add a prefix for all the types. When standing in the middle of `SomeKindOfType` I would like to press a single keystroke, write `My` prefix and then repeat the same insertion two times with `j.` to get this output:

```
random_name: MySomeKindOfType = "foo"
long_name: MyAnotherType = "bar"
short_name: MyThirdType = "spam"
```

I have unsuccessfuly tried defining my own command with [repeat.vim](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/repeat-vim) plugin; it seems not to work with insertion commands such as `i`, `a`, `c`.

Answer (score 1):

Re-hashing what's available in the linked question:

- `ciwMy<C-r>-<esc>j.` (harder to map, I suppose; maybe something with a self-deleting autocommand)
- `qqbiMy<esc>qj@q`
- `/\<\w+Type<CR>iMy<esc>n.`
- `:[range]normal! 0f:wiMy`

Comment: "maybe something with a self-deleting autocommand" -- For the mapping to be repeatable with `.`, the self-deleting autocommand would have to be set from within the single `c` operation, which it could by using `<c-r>=` to call a function that does so, but that expression wouldn't be re-evaluated by `.`, so repeats wouldn't work. Maybe a permanent autocommand.

Comment: @JoL the autocommand I’m thinking of was basically `InsertLeave normal! "-p` (Might need an execute to avoid that double-quote showing as a comment). That’s not going to be good for a permanent thing. OTOH with tpope’s repeat plugin, I think making it repeatable is far easier, but possibly not perfect.

Comment: Yes, I understood, but to set that up you'd need something like `nmap <leader>i cb<c-r>=execute('au InsertLeave * ++once normal "-p')<cr>`. However, while that would work when invoking with `\i`, it wouldn't when trying to repeat it with `.`. It would just put the prefix you insert without restoring the part that was deleted, because vim seems to save the result of the `=` expression instead of re-evaluating for each call of `.`, so you only get the autocommand set-up on the first time.

Comment: For the permanent autocommand, I was wondering if it were possible to know if we just left insert mode of precisely the one started by one particular `nmap`, to only act on those. Also, yes, it may be easier to modify tpope's script. For all I know, the decision to require appending instead of prepending the function call may have been arbitrary, and the switch could be relatively simple.

Comment: @JoL not in general, since mappings are expanded a bit like as if we had used feedkeys. But you could set a magic buffer-local var, check it, and unset it… I wasn’t suggesting modifying repeat, but rather hooking into it.

Comment: To set up the autocommand I would just use `:`, possibly in a function. Would be easier.

Comment: How would you set the var, such that setting it would also work with `.`?

Comment: @JoL hence tpope/repeat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133144/discussion-between-d-ben-knoble-and-jol).