# How can I have multiple cursors while entering insert mode after Visual Block mode?

Tags: insert-mode, visual-mode, cursor, visual-block, plugin-vim-visual-multi

Let's say I have some text:

```
ipsum
ipsum dolor
ipsum dolor sit
```

I want to add the word "Lorem" in front of each line.

```
Loremipsum
Loremipsum dolor
Loremipsum dolor sit
```

I can do this by:

- Entering visual block mode at the first line,
- Going down 2 lines
- Entering insert mode with `Shift-I`
- Typing `Lorem`
- Exit insert mode (with <kbd>Esc</kbd>)

It will indeed put "Lorem" in front of each line but only **after** exiting insert mode.

I would like for multiple cursors to appear, and whatever I type would appear on all three lines, not just the top one.

Is this possible with Vim or a plugin?

Comment: Other solutions: `v2j:s/^/Lorem` (the first bit `v2j` can be replaced by your favorite way to enter a range for that chunk of text), `v2j:norm! ILorem `, `ILorem <esc>j.j.`, etc. `:[range]normal! .` is also really powerful.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4312/10604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in Vim without special customization.

The [vim-visual-multi](https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi) plugin offers such functionality.

For your use case once vim-visual-multi is installed.

- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>down</kbd> to select the part of the column you want to edit (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> + <kbd>down</kbd> would do in standard Vim),
- Use `i` to switch to insert mode,
- Type your text,
- Leave insert mode <kbd>Esc</kbd>,
- Leave multiple cursor mode <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

All the row are edited at the same time.

vim-visual-multi is actually much more capable but this cover your use case.